# What type of serialization uses Wcf behind the scenes?

Tags: wcf

I know there's 3 type s of serialization in .net :

```
Soap , Xml , Binary.
```

Wcf instructed the DataContract attribute which also serialize ... but via **what** ?

Binary is not  - i know.

**So  by which mechanism** ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is the binding defined for the given endpoint which specifies the serialization mechanism. For example:

- `basicHttpBinding` and `wsHttpBinding` use SOAP
- `netTcpBinding` uses binary serialization
- `webHttpBinding` could use XML, Json, ...

You can read more about the different built-in bindings and their properties on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx). Thanks to the extensibility of WCF you could of course write your own custom bindings.

Comment: Soap is not a serialization mechanism.

Answer (score 15):

You are messing two techniques together.

- Serialization - how objects are converted to messages - we have XML and JSON formatters available out of the box (`DataContractSerializer`, `DataContractJsonSerializer`, `XmlSerializer`)
- Encoding - how the message is transferred - we have three encoders out of the box

  - `TextMessageEncoder` - for SOAP messages transferred as text - also supports MTOM and POX (Plain old XML) if message version is set to `None`
  - `BinaryMessageEncoder` - for XML/SOAP messages transferred as binary data
  - `WebMessageEncoder` - for XML and JSON messages in REST services

These features are used by standard bindings. WCF support as many serializations and encoding as you want => you can build your own.

Comment: Is there any implementation of a binary serialization? I do not want the serializer to transmit property names each and every time it sends out a property?

Comment: Can I specify in wshttpbinding to use dataContractJsonSerializer ?

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim: No. WsHttpBinding is for Soap services.